# Central tag repository?

Tags: tags, tagging

Thunderbird tags my email, Flicker tags my images.

I use the same tags and have to repeat them for every webapplication that I use, I'm too lazy for this.

Is there any remedy for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think the set of tags is context-dependent. If one point of tags is to make searching easier by letting you browse a higher-level categorization of tags, then being forced to see hundreds or thousands of tags that are all wrong would make it harder. Then we'd need to start tagging the tags, so keep them separate. I'm not too cloudy though, so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar to the Nostalgy plugin for Thunderbird on a global scale

Nostalgy handles nested tags which appends the context once you associate to the "correct" tag.

I'm using IMAP folder and tag as synonyms in this example.